# Spring MVC map xDomainRequest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internet-explorer

You can only use GET and POST for xDomainRequests. Is there a way I can create a mapping that can also take an optional param to determine which webmethod to use? For example I have:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public SomeObject someUpdateFunction(@RequestBody SomeObject objectToUpdate)
{
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SomeObject someCreateFunction(@RequestBody SomeObject objectToUpdate)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way that I can somehow map an XDR to the PUT method? I obviously don't want to add the POST option to `someUpdateFunction()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O'Reilly book "RESTful Web Services" describes a convention where the intended method is included in a "_method" parameter, either via the query string or the request body.  This is particularly useful when you are dealing with cross-domain ajax requests in IE9 and older, where only GET and POST are allowed.  In that case, you would include a _method param with a value of "PUT".

So, if you follow the convention I just described, perhaps you could do something like this:

```
private SomeObject processPut(objectToUpdate) 
{
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public SomeObject someUpdateFunction(@RequestBody SomeObject objectToUpdate)
{
    return processPut(objectToUpdate);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "_method=PUT")
@ResponseBody
public SomeObject someUpdateFunction(@RequestBody SomeObject objectToUpdate)
{
    return processPut(objectToUpdate);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SomeObject someCreateFunction(@RequestBody SomeObject objectToUpdate)
{
    ...
}
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do this in Spring, as I have very little experience with this framework, but the concept should hold up.